# replace empty space lines on a string column using Python

Tags: python

i am reading an excel data where one of the columns has text based data.

it basically some set of database qry's

if i look at the dataframe:  sel a ,b \n\n\n\n   from database1\n\n\n   where n=1 \n\n\n order by \n; \n\n\n

\n is the new line character.  Some qry lengths are huge and with new line character in between it eats up the space.

I only want to remove the blank lines

example:  sel

```
      col1 ,



      col2  from database 

      order by 1;
```

should reflect as

sel
col1,
col2 from database
order by 1;

Comment: what about the whitespaces before the words (or was that an error) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and easy way to get rid of extraneous whitespace.

```py
In [1]: s = """sel
   ...:
   ...:       col1 ,
   ...:
   ...:
   ...:
   ...:       col2  from database
   ...:
   ...:       order by 1;"""

In [2]: " ".join(s.split())
Out[2]: 'sel col1 , col2 from database order by 1;'
```

Note that this doesn't fix the erroneous whitespace in "col1 , col2". It's not clear from your post how important that is to you. If you want, you can fix it with another split/join:

```py
In [3]: ", ".join(" ".join(s.split()).split(" , "))
Out[3]: 'sel col1, col2 from database order by 1;'
```

If you're working with a dataframe, you can apply the same logic to the entire column of queries at once:

```py
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
                                             queries
0  sel\n\n      col1 ,\n\n\n\n      col2  from da...
1  sel\n\n      col1 ,\n\n\n\n      col2  from da...
2  sel\n\n      col1 ,\n\n\n\n      col2  from da...
3  sel\n\n      col1 ,\n\n\n\n      col2  from da...
4  sel\n\n      col1 ,\n\n\n\n      col2  from da...
5  sel\n\n      col1 ,\n\n\n\n      col2  from da...
6  sel\n\n      col1 ,\n\n\n\n      col2  from da...
7  sel\n\n      col1 ,\n\n\n\n      col2  from da...
8  sel\n\n      col1 ,\n\n\n\n      col2  from da...
9  sel\n\n      col1 ,\n\n\n\n      col2  from da...


In [5]: df["queries"].str.split().apply(" ".join)
Out[5]:
0    sel col1 , col2 from database order by 1;
1    sel col1 , col2 from database order by 1;
2    sel col1 , col2 from database order by 1;
3    sel col1 , col2 from database order by 1;
4    sel col1 , col2 from database order by 1;
5    sel col1 , col2 from database order by 1;
6    sel col1 , col2 from database order by 1;
7    sel col1 , col2 from database order by 1;
8    sel col1 , col2 from database order by 1;
9    sel col1 , col2 from database order by 1;
Name: queries, dtype: object
```

And again, if you also wanted to fix that pesky "col1 , col2":

```py
In [6]: df["queries"].str.split().apply(" ".join).str.split(" , ").apply(", ".join)
Out[6]:
0    sel col1, col2 from database order by 1;
1    sel col1, col2 from database order by 1;
2    sel col1, col2 from database order by 1;
3    sel col1, col2 from database order by 1;
4    sel col1, col2 from database order by 1;
5    sel col1, col2 from database order by 1;
6    sel col1, col2 from database order by 1;
7    sel col1, col2 from database order by 1;
8    sel col1, col2 from database order by 1;
9    sel col1, col2 from database order by 1;
Name: queries, dtype: object
```